# Is $\mathbb{R^2}$ Hausdorff? Give an example of a non-Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-topology, real-numbers

these are two questions on Hausdorff topological spaces. The bit I am having particular difficulty with is finding an 'example of a non-Hausdorff topology on $\mathbb{R}$'

---

A Hausdorff topological space $(X, \tau)$ is such that any distinct points $a, v \in X$ have disjoint open neighbourhoods. i.e. there are open neighbourhoods $U_a, V_b \in \tau$ such that $ a \in U_a  $ and $b \in V_b $ and $U_a \cap V_b = \emptyset$

> Is $\mathbb{R^2}$ Hausdorff?

I believe so. Take $a, b \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Take open neighbourhoods:

$U_a=B_{r_a}(a)=\{(x, y) : |(x, y)-a|<r_a\}$

$V_b=B_{r_b}(b)=\{(x, y) : |(x, y)-b|<r_b\}$

Let $r=d(a,b)$. Take $r_a=r_b=\frac{r}{2}$

So $\mathbb{R^2}$ is Hausdorff.

Is this correct?

> Give an example of a non-Hausdorff topology on the set of real numbers

$\mathbb{R}$ is clearly Hausdorff. What is another example of a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Please could you help me with this one?

Comment: The first part is correct. For the second one, consider for example the indiscrete topology.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is clearly Hausdorff *when considered under the usual topology*. For another (non-Hausdorff) example, consider the topology whose open sets are $\emptyset$ and all subsets $A$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $0\in A.$

Comment: @CameronBuie Hi. What does it mean `when considered under the usual toplogy'

Comment: Well, $\Bbb R$ is a set, and there are many ways one can define a topology on it--including the one I mentioned, those in the answers below, and "the usual one" (that is, the most commonly used and well-recognized of all such topologies). For more details, see for example [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space), especially in the second paragraph under Examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a topology on a set E (here $\mathbb R^2$) is defined by a subset of $\mathcal P(E)$ with special properties (contains $\emptyset$ and E, stable by union and finite intersection) called the set of open sets of E.

Now it appears the simplest possible topology on $\mathbb R^2$, namely $\{\mathbb R^2,\emptyset\}$ (called the trivial topology) perfectly fits your needs, the only neighborhood of any point is $\mathbb R^2$ itself!

To say it with your words, in this topology, given $a,b\in\mathbb R^2$, the only neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ and $U_b$ of $b$ you can find is $U_a=U_b=\mathbb R^2$ and in this case you definitely don't have $U_a\cap U_b=\emptyset$ ! So it's impossible to separate any two points given this topology.

Comment: Thanks. So is a topology just a special kind of set? I have always been confused as to what exactly a topology is; is it a set with some other operation?

Comment: And in the trivial case, why is the neighbourhood of $\emptyset$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The most general definition of topology is the one I hinted at, you can find it on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology#A_topology_on_a_set .
Beware that you can only speek of the neighborhood of a pint in $\mathbb R^2$, you cannot talk of the neighboorhod of a subset like $\emptyset$

Comment: ok thanks. So we just need to consider the neighbourhood of all elements except $\emptyset$ which in the trivial case is $\mathbb{R}$ which is just itself

Comment: No, you have to consider the neighborhood of all elements of $\mathbb R^2$, which are points such as (0,1), (2,3)... the difference is that the open neighborhood of a point can only be $\emptyset$ (which doesn't make sense) or $\mathbb R^2$ itself since they are the only open sets of $\mathbb R^2$ in this topology.

Comment: (I updated my answer for more details)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few "natural" examples, e.g.:

- the trivial topology already mentioned in Mandrathax answer;
- the cofinite topology, where the closed sets are precisely $\Bbb R$, $\emptyset$ and all finite subsets;
- the topology whose non-trivial open sets are the right halflines $(a,\infty)$;
- as the latter but with the left halflines $(-\infty,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

The *cofinite topology* on a set $X$, which is defined by $$\tau = \{ A \subseteq X \, : \, A = \varnothing \text{ or } X \setminus A \text{ is finite} \}$$ is non-Hausdorff (if $X$ is infinite).