# The connected components determined by a path which lies in one of the connected components determined by another path

Tags: algebraic-topology, plane-curves

Let $\alpha$ be a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)) in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $A, B$ be distinct connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\operatorname{Im}\alpha$. Let $\beta$ be a path in $B$. Let $C$ be a connected component of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\operatorname{Im}\beta$. Is it necessarily the case that either $A\cap C=\emptyset$ or $A\subseteq C$?

P.S. Even though I tagged this question with "algebraic-topology", I don't know algebraic topology, and therefore would appreciate as elementary a reply as possible. You can use the Jordan Curve Theorem, and the fact that every open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the disjoint union of a countable number of open, connected sets.

Comment: You want to ask this in algebraic-topology, not algebraic-geometry. I've switched the tag for you.

Comment: @KReiser: I've figured out the answer on my own. Should I delete the question, or answer it?

Comment: It's up to you, and I'm sure you can make a good choice on your own. No need to ask for further input from me on this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** Yes, it is necessarily the case that either $A\cap C=\emptyset$ or $A\subseteq C$.

---

I will prove a more general statement (cf. the Remark below):

**Restatement of the problem** Let $T = \langle\Omega, \tau\rangle$ be a locally-connected space. Let $A \subseteq \Omega$ be connected, and let $F$ be a closed subset of $\Omega\setminus A$. Let $C$ be a connected component of $\Omega\setminus F$. Then $A\cap C=\emptyset$ or $A\subseteq C$.

---

**Proof** Since $\Omega\setminus F$ is open, $\Omega\setminus F$ [is locally connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Subset_of_Locally_Connected_Space_is_Locally_Connected). Denote by $\mathbf{C}$ the set consisting of the connected components of $\Omega\setminus F$. Then $\mathbf{C}$'s members [are open](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Component_of_Locally_Connected_Space_is_Open) and pairwise disjoint. Define $D = \cup\big(\mathbf{C}\setminus\{C\}\big)$. Then $C$ and $D$ are open and mutually disjoint, and $\Omega\setminus F = C\cup D$. Since by assumption $F$ and $A$ are mutually disjoint, $A \subseteq \Omega\setminus F$. Hence, $A \subseteq C\cup D$. [Then](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Subset_of_Union_of_Disjoint_Open_Sets), since $A$ is by assumption connected, either $A \subseteq C$, or $A \subseteq D$. $\square$

---

**Remark**

If $T$ is moreover Hausdorff, then $F$ can be taken to be the image of an arbitrary path $\beta$ in $\Omega\setminus A$. In fact, since $\beta$ is a path, it is [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Path_(topology)&oldid=1062812371#Definition) a continuous function of the compact set $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (w.r.t. the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$) for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a <b$. [Therefore](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact) its image $\operatorname{Im}\beta$ is compact. Since $T$ is Hausdorff, $\operatorname{Im}\beta$ [is closed](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Hausdorff_Space_is_Closed).

Since the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$ [is Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1739058/37058), [as well as locally connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Locally_connected_space&oldid=1061749200#First_examples), the restated proposition resolves the original question in its original formulation.

Comment: What is the purpose of $B$? Why don't you consider any path in $\Omega \setminus A$? And why do you consider paths? It suffices to take closed subsets of $\Omega \setminus A$ instead of images of paths.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Done. Thanks!